# Generating multiple page reports (Page Per Report) using ArcGIS Pro & Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-toolbox

I have reached a point a little bit outside of my knowledge frame. Python.

I found that I can create multiple page reports with Python in ArcGIS Pro by combine 2 reports together. I am following [this link from ESRI's site](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/report-class.htm#GUID-B8E9C245-9AB6-48ED-8919-9A3D7C323BB1). I am using Report example 3.

I continue to get the following message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):|File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'aprx'
```

I have tried several thing but lack an understanding.

What would my next step be?

Create a tool box that would allow me to make this a little more stream lined?

How do I define 'self'?

Comment: Where do you run the script in example 3? in a tool box or arcgis python console?

Comment: You cannot take example 3 by itself and it'll "work". It is an incomplete, and actually misleading or incorrect code sample. Its calling `self.aprx`, indicating that it may have been a copy of code from a bigger object.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I was going through arcgis python console. After playing with the script I came up with something that was able to merge the two PDF files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a missing part in example 3. `self` is unknown. As @KHibma stated, it might be a part of a bigger project, probably a Python tool.

I am not able to test right now, but removing `self`s and specifying `aprx` would solve the problem if you don't make a python tool.

Try in this way:

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\path\to\file.aprx") # add a full path

# other lines

report1 = aprx.listReports(...
report2 = aprx.listReports(...

# other lines
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I ended up with. Thank you Kadir and @Khibma both for the input.